# AJAX jQuery Avatar Uploading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to find a very basic AJAX jQuery Avatar Uploading that I can use for my "settings" page so users can upload an avatar and unfortunately I can't find any.

This is my "function" so far for uploading the avatar

```
    function uploadAvatar(){
    $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
    $('#avatarDialog').html("Logging in, please wait....");
    dataString = $('#avatarForm').serialize();
    var postURL = $('#avatarForm').attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url+"/libraries/ajax/image-upload.php",
        data:dataString,
        dataType:"json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.err){
                $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
                $('#avatarDialog').html(data.err);
            }else if(data.msg){
                $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
                $('#avatarDialog').html(data.msg);

                var delay = 2000;
                window.setTimeout(function(){          
                    location.reload(true);
                }, delay);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

For my HTML/Input is this.

```
<form id="avatar_form" action enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="image_file" id="imageInput" type="file" />
<input type="submit"  id="submit-btn" onClick="uploadAvatar();" value="Upload" />
```

And finally this is my PHP code (I have nothing here)

```
$thumb_square_size      = 200;
$max_image_size         = 500; 
$thumb_prefix           = "thumb_"; 
$destination_folder     = './data/avatars/';
$jpeg_quality           = 90; //jpeg quality


$return_json = array();
if($err==""){ $return_json['msg'] = $msg; }
else{ $return_json['err'] = $err; }
echo json_encode($return_json); 
exit;
```

So how do I start this really. I just don't know where to start, I don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: Your form has nothing for `action` - `<form id="avatar_form" action enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't, it's not suppose to be there actually. Hehe, because the login() in the submit input will grab the file that is needed to execute the action. It doesn't do anything even when it is there, just forgot to remove it.

Comment: You have `onClick="avatar();"` but I don't see a function called `avatar()`, but one called `uploadAvatar()`.

Comment: Like I said, I make mistakes xD....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulletproof is a nice PHP image upload class which encorporates common security concerns and practices, so we will use it here as it also makes the whole process much simpler and cleaner. You will want to read the approved answer on this question here (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form) to better understand the risks of accepting file uploads from users.

The PHP below is really basic and really only handle the image upload. You would want to save the path or the file name that was generated in a database or in some kind of storage if the image is uploaded successfully.

You may also want to change the directory in which the image is uploaded to. To do this, change the parameter for `->uploadDir("uploads")` to some other relative or absolute path. This value `"uploads"` will upload the image to the `libraries/ajax/uploads` directory. If the directory does not exist, bulletproof will first create it.

You will need to download bulletproof (https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof) and make sure to upload or place it in `libraries/bulletproof/`. When you download the class from github it will be in a ZIP archive. Extract the zip archive and rename bulletproof-master director to just plain bulletproof. Place that directory in the libraries directory.

HTML

```
    <form id="avatar_form" action enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input name="image_file" id="imageInput" type="file" />
        <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

JS

```
$('#avatar_form').submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); //use form data, not serialized string
    $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
    $('#avatarDialog').html("Logging in, please wait....");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url + "/libraries/ajax/image-upload.php",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.code != 200){ //response code other than 200, error
                $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
                $('#avatarDialog').html(data.msg);
            } else { // response code was 200, everything is OK
                $('#avatarDialog').fadeIn();
                $('#avatarDialog').html(data.msg);
                var delay = 2000;
                window.setTimeout(function(){          
                    location.reload(true);
                }, delay);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
    //bulletproof image uploads
    //https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof
    require_once('../bulletproof/src/bulletproof.php');
    $bulletproof = new ImageUploader\BulletProof;

    //our default json response
    $json = array('code' => 200, 'msg' => "Avatar uploaded!");

    //if a file was submitted
    if($_FILES)
    {
        try
        {
            //rename the file to some unique
            //md5 hash value of current timestamp and a random number between 0 & 1000
            $filename = md5(time() . rand(0, 1000));
            $result = $bulletproof->fileTypes(["png", "jpeg"])  //only accept png/jpeg image types
                    ->uploadDir("uploads")  //create folder 'pics' if it does not exist.
                    ->limitSize(["min" => 1000, "max" => 300000])  //limit image size (in bytes) .01mb - 3.0mb
                    ->shrink(["height" => 96, "width" => 96])  //limit image dimensions
                    ->upload($_FILES['image_file'], $filename);  // upload to folder 'pics'

            //maybe save the filename and other information to a database at this point

           //print the json output                
           print_r(json_encode($json));        
        } 
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $json['code'] = 500;
            $json['msg'] = $e->getMessage();
            print_r(json_encode($json));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //no file was submitted
        //send back a 500 error code and a error message
        $json['code'] = 500;
        $json['msg'] = "You must select a file";
        print_r(json_encode($json));
    }
```

Bulletproof will throw an exception if the image does not pass the validation tests. We catch the exception in the try catch block and return the error message back to the JavaScript in the JSON return.

The rest of the code is commented pretty well from the Bulletproof github page etc, but comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thanks for the commenting in the code as well as explaining it all. I'll surely be using this. Thanks for everything, +9K

Comment: Also, there's an error with this part of the code

    $result = $bulletproof->fileTypes(["png", "jpeg"])  //only accept png/jpeg image types
                    ->uploadDir("uploads")  //create folder 'pics' if it does not exist.
                    ->limitSize(["min" => 1000, "max" => 300000])  //limit image size (in bytes) .01mb - 3.0mb
                    ->shrink(["height" => 96, "width" => 96])  //limit image dimensions
                    ->upload($_FILES['image_file'], $filename);  // upload to folder 'pics'

Comment: What is the error your are receiving? I was able to successfully upload images using the code above.

Comment: I don't know what kind of error it is, I've tried the common tricks to get it to work and it's not doing anything.

http://i.gyazo.com/485be5cee9e7587d609204135cdfa9a0.png

Comment: What editor are you using there? It may be that the editor does not like how the methods are chained, or there is some kind of newline or return in the string that is causing a parsing error.

Remove all the comments and try this.

Comment: This will probably help you too, I checked Console in Firefox and I get the 500 Internal Server Error : http://i.gyazo.com/1ebe95bf6ee5010cb06663e0d84d5a41.png... I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS6

Comment: I removed the comments and still the same issue. http://i.gyazo.com/df4e30c0be20f6202f12311323d4cfa5.png

Comment: What editor are you using there? The only thing I can think of from it simply highlighting the line is it either did not load the bulletproof library from the relative path, or it does not like the chaining of the method. Does this make any difference?

`$result = $bulletproof->fileTypes(["png", "jpeg"])->uploadDir("uploads")->limitSize(["min" => 1000, "max" => 300000])->shrink(["height" => 96, "width"=> 96])->upload($_FILES['image_file'], $filename);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72643/discussion-between-ronburgundy-and-cameron-swyft).

Comment: @Ronburgundy if you use the `upload()` method without a second argument, BP will generate a name itself, as seen in the [README](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof) page. You don't have to generate a name by yourself. other than that really good answer `+1` from me

Comment: Thanks Sam, I use Bulletproof on several projects so I am happy to spread the word when applicable. It is nice that Bulletproof will generate a name for us, however I wanted to demonstrate to the OP how to create their own unique strings / file names for further reference. Thanks for making Bulletproof available.

Comment: I am glad my code is useful, I have finished making `v-2.0` make sure to check it out on github after a week or two. It is way better than the current version, with very simplified syntax and some added features. If you have anything on you wish list, let me know ;)